# How to run update-grub at load time in Debian 8?

Tags: linux, boot, grub

- OS: Debian 8
- logged with rescue image
- HDD LVM

Set a password for grub, and it seems did missed some hash digit when copied encrypted password in `40_custom`,
I managed to removed login/password details from `grub` `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` using rescue disk.
but now  `update-grub` needs to be run, sins grub is not loading, and neater the kernel, obviously setting a cron job to run it is useless,...
Does anyone knows if there is a solution to add a command to grub, to run `update-grub` at load time in `GRUB_CMDLINE_DEFAULT="command_to_run_update-grub"` ?
Or may be there is a way to do manually whatever update-grub does?

Answer (score 1):

No need to reinstall GRUB. Since you managed to access `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`, use the same method to access `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`, find the exact same login/password details in that file, and comment them out (or just delete them). They will be between lines like:

```
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
< ... here is a copy of GRUB password settings you removed from /etc/grub.d/40_custom...>
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
```

The files in `/etc/grub.d/` are scripts which will participate in creating the actual GRUB configuration file. In particular, the `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` has two lines in the beginning, which will cause the rest of the file to be copied verbatim into the actual GRUB configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have access to the root filesystem using some external applications, why don't you just reinstall `grub`? That way you can boot to your system once again.

[Here's a tutorial on how to reinstall `grub` on a Debian distro.](https://feeding.cloud.geek.nz/posts/reinstalling-grub-on-unbootable-debian/) Based off of this tutorial, you could also try running the update on the rescue mode without reinstalling.

Also, if you want to keep your `grub` configs, you can copy them to some external storage to not lose them after the installation.